# Por que é preciso passar dois then nas requisições AJAX feitas com a API fetch?

Tags: javascript, promises, fetch

No exemplo da seguinte requisição:

```
fetch("https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/")
  .then(resposta => resposta.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```

No primeiro `then` já não deveria receber uma resposta completa do servidor? No primeiro `then` eu já  tentei dar um `console.log`, mas não consigo encontrar onde está o JSON dentro do objeto retornado. Apenas no segundo `then` recebo esse dado, o que me deixou confuso. Se no primeiro `then` eu não tenho essa informação, por que eu teria no segundo se ele é um *callback* do primeiro?

Answer (score 6):

O retorno `response` do fetch é uma *stream*, e para extrair o seu conteúdo ([Body.json() na API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)) usa-se `response.json()` que é assíncrono e retorna ele próprio uma Promise. Assim ou se usa `async`/`await` ou dois `.then`...

Com `async`/`await`:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')
  .then(async response => {
    const dados = await response.json();
    console.log('Tudo correu bem!');
    console.log('Qtd de dados:', dados.length);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Houve um erro!', err))
  .finally(() => console.log('The end!...'));
```

Ou usando 2 `.then`:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((dados) => {
    console.log('Tudo correu bem!');
    console.log('Qtd de dados:', dados.length);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Houve um erro!', err))
  .finally(() => console.log('The end!...'));
```

Answer (score 5):

A [API `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) retorna uma `Promise` com um [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Response), que contém vários dados relativos à resposta da requisição, como o *status*, URL ou o próprio corpo ([`body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Body/body)).

No entanto, a propriedade `body` de `Response` é um [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream), o que tornaria o seu uso direto relativamente custoso para uma API que visa ser de fácil uso. Desse modo, por conveniência, `Response` também possui alguns métodos como o `json`, `text` e [outros](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Response#M%C3%A9todos), que auxiliam na conversão do corpo, um `ReadableStream`, para formatos mais facilmente utilizáveis.

Para isso, esses métodos (como `json` ou `text`) devem também retornar uma outra `Promise`, já que geralmente o trabalho com Streams é assíncrono.

Portanto, como estamos trabalhando com duas promessas (uma retornada pelo `fetch` e outra retornada pelo método `json` de `Response`), você tem que encadeá-las usando o `then`:

```
fetch('<url>') /* `fetch` retorna uma promessa. */
  .then /* Liga-se à resolução da promessa do `fetch`. */ ((response) => response.json() /* `json` retorna OUTRA promessa. */ )
  .then /* Liga-se à resolução da promessa método `json` de `Response`. */ ((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Para demonstrar que trabalha-se com duas promessas, se utilizarmos `async`/`await`, teríamos que usar o operador `await` duas vezes, uma para resolver a promessa de `fetch` e o outro para resolver a promessa de `json`:

```js
async function main() {
  // Espera a resolução da promessa do `fetch`.
  //               ↓↓↓↓↓
  const response = await fetch('<url>');

  // Espera a resolução da promessa do `json`.
  //           ↓↓↓↓↓
  const data = await response.json();

  console.log(data);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

---

Desse modo, clarificando alguns trechos da pergunta:

> No primeiro `then` já não deveria receber uma resposta completa do servidor?

Sim, e é exatamente isso que está ocorrendo. O `fetch` retorna uma `Promise` com `Response`, um objeto que contém várias propriedades da resposta – incluindo o seu corpo. Apesar disso, o corpo ainda não está no formato que desejamos, o que faz necessário o uso de métodos como o `json`:  para converter `body`, um Stream, em um JSON.

> Se no primeiro `then` eu não tenho essa informação, por que eu teria no segundo se ele é um *callback* do primeiro?

O segundo `then` não é, de modo algum, um *callback* do primeiro. O segundo `then` é uma ferramenta de aguardar a resolução do método `json` presente em `Response`. São duas coisas diferentes.

Veja:

```js
fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('Propriedades e métodos de `response`:');
    console.log(Object.keys(response.__proto__));
    
    // Note que deste `then` estamos retornando uma outra promessa.
    // Isso porque este método `json` retorna uma OUTRA `Promise`.
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('Agora sim temos o nosso JSON "parseado":');
    console.log(data.length); // Número de dados retornados pela API. Não interessa para a explicação.
  });
```

Vale dizer que logo que o primeiro `then` é executado, isto é, a promessa de `fetch` é resolvida, a requisição já foi terminada e o seu corpo está na memória do navegador. A partir daí, só falta transformar a Stream no JSON. :)

<sup>Repeti várias vezes algumas coisas nesta resposta, espero que não tenha ficado chata.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro `then` retorna uma `promise`([Uma Promise é um objeto que representa a eventual conclusão ou falha de uma operação assincrona.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usando_promises)) do tipo [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Response/Response) onde é definido pelo desenvolvedor qual tipo deseja receber.

Esse [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Response/Response) tem [métodos e propriedades](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body) e para definir qual é o tipo do retorno o desenvolvedor escolhe alguns dos métodos logo abaixo que também é uma `promise`:

- [arrayBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer)
- [blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Body/blob)
- [json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Body/json)
- [text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Body/text)
- [formData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Body/formData)

Para que fique mais claro o código pode ser escrito dessa forma onde demonstra que se a resposta do primeiro `then` for satisfatória (`resposta.ok`) pode ser executado o próximo método dos precitados e que no caso foi `json()`, ***exemplo***:

```js
fetch("https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/")
 .then(resposta => {
    if (resposta.ok) { // deu certo a requisição
        resposta.json().then(json => console.log(json))
    }
});
```

Isso significa que o segundo `then` é referente a resposta do `primeiro` e normalmente são chamados um logo após o outro parecendo ser uma coisa só. Utilizando `async/await` pode ser resumido assim:

```
async function source() {
    try {
       const res = await fetch("https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/");
       if (res.ok) { // requisição deu certo ...
          const json = await res.json();
          console.log(json);
       }
    } catch (e) {
       console.log(e);
    }
}
```

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Usando Fetch - Body](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Response_objects)
- [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Response/Response)